# Fill in an Input Box in Chrome with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to write a line of code in JavaScript that changes the input value on an input box on a website. The problem is that there are 3 other input boxes with the same class name (there aren't any ID's, just classes). Is there any way to get around this?

Here is the html code:

```
<div class="ut-numeric-input-spinner-control">
   <button class="btn-standard decrement-value"></button>
      <input type="tel" class="numericInput filled" placeholder="Any">
   <button class="btn-standard increment-value"></button>
</div>
```

There is the exact same of this html repeated 3 more times.

Comment: You could always `document.getElementsByClassName('numericInput')[0]` but why can't you add id tags? Then, it's much more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @KevinBai As i said there are 4 divs with the exact same code above. I can't add id tags because its not my website or is there a way I can add ID tags?

Comment: you can use document.getElementsByClassName("numericInput filled")[0], [1], [2] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName

Comment: Well, which one are you trying to fill in? Others have mentioned `getElementsByClassName`, but you can use `querySelectorAll(".numericInput")[index]` as well. There may be ways of targeting the correct input based on other elements that provide further context that you haven't shown.